# K-frame sun-sky component for A-Frame on mobile

Tags: aframe

I'm unable to view the a-sun-sky component on any mobile browser. Also the sun-position-setter becomes inverted with the sun passing below the camera. Is this component compatible with mobile?
It works great on PC though.
https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/sun-sky/

Comment: I haven't tested on mobile so it is possible it doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: No worries...as a cheat I've taken a panorama screenshot of <a-sun-sky> and loaded the img in <a-sky>